# Using for loop on where() method

Tags: c#, .net-core, checkbox

So I have a search-input and checkboxes that passes the values to the controller when there are inputs. And I want to use these values to get something back from the database. The search-input is a string and it works and intended. Here is the code for the search-input:

```
public async Task<ViewResult> Index(string searchString, List<int> checkedTypes)
{
    var products = from p in _db.Products select p;

    ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;
    
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        products = products.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString));
    }
    
    return View(products);
}
```

However the checkboxes values are stored in a list. So basically I want to do the same as the code above, but with a list. So basically an idea is like this:

```
if(checkedTypes != null)
{
    foreach (var i in checkedTypes)
    {
        products = products.Where(p => p.TypeId == i));
    }              
}
```

If I do it like the code above, I just get the last (i) from the loop. Another solution I did was this:

```
if(checkedTypes != null)
{
    var temp = new List<Product>();
    
    foreach (var i in checkedTypes)
    {
        temp.AddRange(products.Where(p => p.TypeId == i));
    }
    products = temp.AsQueryable();
}
```

But when I did it like that I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IAsyncQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

So anyone have a solution that I can use? Or is there a better way to handle checkboxes in the controller?

Comment: Please consider what repeatedly tacking on `products = products.Where(p => p.TypeId == i));` will do. Essentially you will say "I want only items with TypeId 10, then of those I only want those with TypeId 11". Hint, there will be none with 11 at this point, only those with 10, but then the net result is that you will get neither because no item will have a TypeId of 10 **and** 11. It will **only** work if there is only 1 item in `checkedTypes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using EF Core (also the same is true for linq2db) - it supports translating filtering with local collection, i.e. `Where(x => checkedTypes.Contains(x.SomeId))`.

If you have "and" logic to filter by `searchString` and `checkedTypes` than you can conditionally add `Where` clause:

```
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
  {
       products = products.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString));
  }

  if(checkedTypes != null)
  {
       products = products.Where(p => checkedTypes.Contains(p.TypeId));    
  }
```

P.S.

Also you should be able to change your first line to:

```
var products = _db.Products.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: @TanveerBadar no cause `var` will be `DbSet` and OP will not be able to assign queryable to the same variable later.

Comment: ' if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
  {
       products = products.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString));
  }

  if(checkedTypes != null)
  {
       products = products.Where(p => checkedTypes.Contains(p.TypeId));    
  }

@Guro Stron, You sir are amazing. When I look at it now, I kinda feel stupid why I haven't thought about that. But it works now. Thank you so much

Comment: @zlatan114r was glad to help!